# How do I show or hide the <option>s based on what is clicked from an outside radio button group?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I am building a form using jQuery that dynamically adds select fields with incrementing ids when the user clicks "Add More".  I need to be able to show or hide certain options based on what the user selected earlier in the form.

When the user clicks "A" from the radio group, then "Div A1" will be hidden. When the user clicks "B", "Div B1" will be hidden, but "Div A1" will be shown, etc. etc.

What's the best way to go about doing that?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show_hide_div_list').hide();

  $('#hide_div_A').click(function() {
    $('.show_hide_div_list').show();
  });

  $('#hide_div_B').click(function() {
    $('.show_hide_div_list').show();
  });

  $('#hide_div_C').click(function() {
    $('.show_hide_div_list').show();
  });

  $('#hide_div_D').click(function() {
    $('.show_hide_div_list').show();
  });

  var show_hide_div_max_fields = 36;
  var show_hide_div_x = 0;

  $('#show_hide_div_add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (show_hide_div_x < show_hide_div_max_fields) {
      show_hide_div_x++;
      var inps = $('#show_hide_div_wrapper >div:last').data('count') + 1 || 1;
      $('#show_hide_div_wrapper').append('<div class="show_hide_div" data-count="' + inps + '"><select id="show_hide_div"><option value="div_a" id="div_a' + inps + '">Div A' + inps + '</option><option value="div_b' + inps + '" id="div_b' + inps + '">Div B' + inps + '</option><option value="div_c' + inps + '" id="div_c' + inps + '">Div C' + inps + '</option><option value="div_d' + inps + '" id="div_d' + inps + '">Div D' + inps + '</option></select><a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br></div>');

    }
    $('#show_hide_div_wrapper').on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
      var inps = $('#show_hide_div_wrapper > div:last').data('count') - 1 || 1;
      show_hide_div_x--;
      $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="show_hide_div">
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      Select which options you want to hide
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_A" value="A">
      <br>
      <label>B</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_B" value="B">
      <br>
      <label>C</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_C" value="C">
      <br>
      <label>D</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_D" value="D">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="show_hide_div_list" style="line-height:1em;">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="show_hide_div_wrapper">      
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="show_hide_div_list">
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="show_hide_div_add">Add More</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are the steps missing in your code? Also why not give a class and do `$('.hide_divs').click(function() {
    $('.show_hide_div_list').show();
  });`

Comment: Wow! I didn't even think of that.  That saves a lot of time and space in my coding.   What do you mean by what steps are missing?  My problem is, by clicking a radio button from the group, it doesn't hide the div so the user can't even select it or even know it's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show_hide_div_list').hide();
  var divArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
  divArray.forEach(function (item) {
      $('#hide_div_' + item).click(function () {
          $('.show_hide_div_list').show()
      })  
  });
  
  var show_hide_div_max_fields = 36;
  var show_hide_div_x = 0;

  $('#show_hide_div_add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      var optionArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
      optionArray.forEach(function (item) {
          if ($('#hide_div_' + item).prop('checked')) {
              if (show_hide_div_x < show_hide_div_max_fields) {
                  show_hide_div_x++;
                  var inps = $('#show_hide_div_wrapper >div:last').data('count') + 1 || 1;
                  
                  var div = $('<div>').addClass('show_hide_div').prop('data-count', inps);
              var select = $('<select>').prop('id', 'show_hide_div');
              optionArray.forEach(function (_item) {
                  if (_item != item) {
                      var option = $('<option>').prop('id', 'div_' + _item + inps).text('Div ' + _item);
                      select.append(option);
                  }                  
              })
              div.append(select).append('<a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br>');
              $('#show_hide_div_wrapper').append(div);
               }              
          }
      });
    
    $('#show_hide_div_wrapper').on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
      var inps = $('#show_hide_div_wrapper > div:last').data('count') - 1 || 1;
      show_hide_div_x--;
      $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="show_hide_div">
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      Select which options you want to hide
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_A" value="A">
      <br>
      <label>B</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_B" value="B">
      <br>
      <label>C</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_C" value="C">
      <br>
      <label>D</label>
      <input type="radio" name="hide_div" id="hide_div_D" value="D">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="show_hide_div_list" style="line-height:1em;">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="show_hide_div_wrapper">      
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="show_hide_div_list">
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="show_hide_div_add">Add More</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked great!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Obviously I needed to tweak it a bit to get it perfect for my actual situation, but it was fairly easy to tell what was going on, and where to make the appropriate changes.  Once I got it tweaked, it's PERFECT!  Thank you so much

Comment: @Matt Glad to help you :)

Comment: I came across a snag in this example.  It doesn't seem to increment.  Each time I click "Add More" it either doesn't add another drop down, or when I tweak it to where it does, it doesn't increment like I need it to.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Matt Change line `$('#show_hide_div_wrapper').html(div);` to `$('#show_hide_div_wrapper').append(div);`. Check again for my update.

Comment: I already had it as 
     $('#show_hide_div_wrapper').append(div);

Comment: In the example above, it doesn't increment either, it starts off with A1, B1, C1, D1, but when I click "Add More" It adds another set but it's still A1, B1, C1, and D1

Answer (score 0):

Set list of ids to be hide and show on radio button click.

```
<input type="radio" name="hide_div" data-hide='["div_A", "div_B"]' data-show='["div_C", "div_D"]' value="A" class="class_name">

 $(document).on("click", ".class_name" ,function(e) {
   var to_hide =  $(this).data('hide');
   var to_show =  $(this).data('show');

   //now you have array of ids to hide and show
   to_hide.forEach(function(item) {
      $(# + item).hide();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with JSON, and am kind of confused by your example.  When I add it to my code (regardless where I put it), it breaks the "Add More" function

Comment: There isn't anything about json here..See updated code it will also work. eg: http://jsfiddle.net/ktw4v/12/

Comment: Share console log to track reason of breaking "Add More" function